# How to handle that can not get form data by using RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I implement a controller as the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> Export(HttpServletRequest req,     HttpServletResponse response, String type,String text) {
........        
}
```

When posting the text(form param) which the length is small(about 20k) from client, the controller works ok and can get form params(data and type).

But 'type' and 'text' are null in service side, when text(form param) is very long(more than 200k) from client.

Who know how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Form `params` can be read from request as `req.getParameter("type")`.
change your method as below since you are already using `req` and `resp` in the method signature

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> Export(HttpServletRequest req,     HttpServletResponse response){
   String type = req.getParameter("type");
   String text = req.getParameter("text");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Spring MVC annotation as follows.

```
public @ResponseBody void export(@PathVariable final String whatEver,
        @RequestParam("type") final String type, @RequestParam("text") final String text,
        final HttpServletRequest request)
```